# Как сделать Activer Ragdoll в 2D игре

Tags: unity3d

Уже месяц мучаюсь, не хотел никого доставать своими вопросами, но уже всё... Сделал регдолл, а когда анимирую его через скрипт баланса, то всё рушится. Очень интересно, как реализовано движение стикмена в игру Stick Fight. Уже весь ютюб облазил, говорят IK использовать, но можно ли как-то без него?
P.S. рушиться в плане не разлетаются части регдолла, а просто он не ходит нормально.